# Проблемы с ::selection в Safari

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Почему-то у некоторых элементов в safari цвет выделения не изменяется, а остается системным

```css
::selection {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
}

body {
  color: black;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

i {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h2> Проблемный текст
  <i> все в порядке </i>
</h2>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/allkrain/pen/BGZwvq)

Answer (score 1):

Видать потому что, данное свойство там [не поддерживается](https://caniuse.com/#search=selection) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Речь не об IOS Safari, а о desktop, а там оно поддерживается - 2 колонки левее